# calculate the average rating on a review system

Tags: php, review, rate

need to calculate the average rating on a review system 
My review has 3 items: `comfort`, `price`, `clean` - Allow between 0 and 5

`INSERT INTO review (id, comfort, price, cleanliness) values ​​(1, 3, 5, 2);
INSERT INTO review (id, comfort, price, cleanliness) values ​​(2, 2, 4, 4);`

when I list the contents of the review I will have to calculate the average of each item... 
I would be better to keep media in a separate table to avoid having to calculate every time?
`insert into company (id, rate_ comfort, rate_ price, rate_ cleaning, description) values ​​(1, 3, 5, 3, 'text description');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(comfort), AVG(price), AVG(cleanliness)
FROM review
```

is all you'd really need. Without any grouping/where clauses, the averages will be calculated for all records in the table.

Comment: thank you very much, I will test it easy, i think it was just that... will solve a big problem